# Duplicate Search Results in indexed search in combination with news pagination

Tags: typo3

indexed search from TYPO3 11 indexes every paginated page of news list pages.

Problem is, that we do have long pages with many content and news lists at the end of the page. Indexed search indexes the page with content correctly. But the news lists in the bottom of the page does have pagination links and so it is possible to call the page with a pagination index:

```
https://mydomain.de/managen/marketing/1/
https://mydomain.de/managen/marketing/2/
https://mydomain.de/managen/marketing/3/
```

Every call results i a valid page and the results are many duplicate search results in indexed search.

Any idea for avoiding this?

Thanks!!

Comment: I would try to change the meta tag and set `noindex` as soon as a pagination is recognized. IndexedSearch would have to respect this (and so would "normal" search engines - they don't like duplicate content either)

Comment: Thanks für your answer! Problem is that indexed search does not respect the meta tags. This pages are set to noindex already.

Comment: Oh... I haven't worked with IndxedSearch for quite a while... :-( Regarding `\TYPO3\CMS\IndexedSearch\Hook\TypoScriptFrontendHook::indexPageContent()`, maybe you can modify the page in TSFE, and set `no_search=0`.